# How do I create a custom view class Programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, custom-view

I want to create a very simple customView with a few UIlabel on it, How should i do this . any tutorial or suggestion would be appreciated . I am new to this , didn't try before.

I tried this with xib.

```
@interface MyCustomView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Label;

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "MyCustomTimer.h"
@implementation MyCustomView
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
      if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])){
      [self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self     options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
       }
     return self;
}
@end
```

But i need to do it programmatically ,please help . thanks

Comment: This question is too broad for a simple QA question here.  Go through the book above which covers everything programmatically.

Comment: @Ezimettekin You want to create a custom view in already existed class or you want to create a UIView class with nib file

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is a simple way, hope it helps you.

```
//in subclassed UIView 
#import "CustomView.h"
@implementation CustomView

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 { 
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    // initilize all your UIView components
    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,30, 200, 44)];
    label1.text = @"i am label 1";
    [self addSubview:label1]; //add label1 to your custom view

    UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,80, 200, 44)];
    label2.text = @"i am label 2";
    [self addSubview:label2]; //add label2 to your custom view



    [label1 release];//i am using without ARC, comment if u are using ARC
    [label2 release];//i am using without ARC, comment if u are using ARC
  }
   return self;
  }



   // in your class where u want to use that view
  #import "ViewController.h"
  #import "CustomView.h"//import it

  @interface ViewController ()

  @end

  @implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
     [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //create your view where u want
    CustomView *cv = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 230, 400)];   //create an instance of your custom view
     [self.view addSubview:cv]; // add to your main view
    [cv release];//comment if u are using ARC
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You say you don't want to use a XIB and want to do it all programmatically.

You need to implement the `initWithFrame:` method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // create/initialize your subviews here
        self.myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init...];

        // configure the label
        self.myLabel.font = ...;
        self.myLabel.autoresizingMask = ...;

        [self addSubview:self.myLabel];
    }

    return self;
}
```

So you create and configure your controls (fonts, colours, autoresizing masks etc.) and add them as subviews, all from the `initWithFrame:` method. You probably want to break the code out into different methods to keep things clean.

If you are using autolayout, you also want to create all your constraints from the init method.

If you are *not* using autolayout, you should implement the `-layoutSubviews` method. This will be called at appropriate times to layout your subviews (e.g. when the frame of your view changes):

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    self.myLabel.frame = ...;
}
```

From the `layoutSubviews` method you can access `self.bounds` to figure out the size of the view at that time. This will let you know how much width/height you have to align or wrap things correctly.

When it comes to creating an instance of your view, just use `[[MyCustomView alloc] init]` (which will call `initWithFrame:` with an empty rect) or `[[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:...]`. Set its frame and add it to some view. The `layoutSubviews` method will be called at all the appropriate times and it will be layed out accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Update your class to implement `initWithFrame:` as well as `initWithCoder:`, then you can call:

```
[[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
```

In your code. Thus you have created an instance (that is configured) programatically.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:...];
        // configure the label
        [self addSubview:label];
    }
 return self;
}
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: 1. if I want to create a custom view that its *width* is to be relative to its superView then no manipulation (related to superview) can be done in the customView class. The constraints can only be done when it's actually added to the superView. 2. If I don't want its width to be relative then I can simply init it with a fixed frame, or something just based on the screen size 3. In the customView I'm able to subviews (labels, textField, etc) and their constraints to the customView

Comment: @Honey it usually isn't quite that simple. views generally have their autoresizing mask converted into constraints now so it depends how that's configured. You can also use the layout subviews and update constraints functions to update the rules that are applied...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you...what I'm ultimately asking is can a class set its frame/constraints relative to it's superView—from its own class? Or it has to always be from the superView?

Comment: A view's frame is in the context of it's superviews bounds, but who sets it doesn't matter. A view can set it's own frame. It would generally be classed as bad practice for the subview to know about the superviews frame though...

Answer (score 2):

You can place these lines in your initWithFrame:

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame]
if (self!=null) {
// if self has been allocated

UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 40)];
[label setText:@"Label"];
[label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
[self addSubview:label];
}
```

Its a very simple example .. to add just one label you can add as many objects you want programatically.. with your desired locations and frame sizes and whatever properties you want...

perhaps you should have searched "UILabel programatically..

Answer (score 2):

Create your own class subclassing UIView, then override initWithFrame or drawRect. Overriding initWithFrame is easier for a newbie.

Your header (.h) file should start with this:

```
@interface YourOwnView : UIView

 ...

 @end
```

Then, in the implementation file (.m) you should implement your own initWithFrame.

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) {
       //ADDING NEW CONTENT
       UILabel *yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
      //CUSTOMIZE your label's font, text, etc.
        ....

      //Add your label to your own view
      [self addSubview:yourLabel];
    }

    return self;
 }
```

You might need extra data or options in the initializer, for example the text for labels. In this case you could define an init method with extra arguments like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andLabelText:(NSString *)labelText;
```